# Git clients in OSX

Tags: macos, git

Now i know there are loads of posts on this subject and i have tried a number of these clients but they don't seem to offer what i need.

**I need a client that will allow me to commit/update git repositories i have stored on a linux server,** but all the clients i have tried only allow me to either enter github credentials or create/use repositories on the local system.

This client has to work on OSX.

Are there any clients that will allow me to check out a project using a url?

Comment: Every Git client will do. Please recheck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Git client will do, you can do that from console as well, just point it to a different repository (not the one on github nor the one on your computer).
My Git needs are solved by command line only but If you need a graphical client I've heard that 'tower' is quite good: http://www.git-tower.com/

Comment: Git Tower is really nice but the first thing it asks you to do is enter either your github or beanstalk account details.

Comment: even if, that should'n stop you from using other repositories

Comment: I understand what you mean now, once i entered my github login details it allowed me to clone from other repositories. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/download.html) and in the occurring Welcome dialog select the Clone option. Then paste your remote Git-repository URL and continue.

Comment: I checked out SmartGrid and its very nice. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

GitX is also very nice and works very well. It has multiple repos on Github with different forks these days. I prefer this fork: https://github.com/laullon/gitx/downloads